Gap results for squares times cubes
In studying the distribution of squarefree numbers in short intervals, Filaseta and Trifonov used some ingenious techniques to obtain various upper bounds for the size of the set
$$
S(X) = \left\{u\in(X,2X]: u^2 a \in (x,x+h]\ \text{for some $a$} \right\}.
$$
Here $h \leq X \leq \sqrt{x}$ and $h = o(x)$ (actually $h$ is about $x^{1/5}$ in their paper). The authors use a variety of techniques, including modified differences (which arise from Padé approximants) and divided differences (arising from the mean value theorem), to show that the elements $u$ of $S(X)$ enjoy nice spacing properties (i.e. the elements can't cluster together much).
I'm curious if anyone has used similar (or completely different) techniques to consider this question in more dimensions. For instance, has anyone considered the problem of giving upper bounds for the size of
$$
S(X,Y) = \left\{(u,v)\in(X,2X]\times(Y,2Y]: a u^2 v^3 \in (x,x+h]\ \text{for some $a$} \right\}?
$$
From some initial calculations, it seems that the methods of the paper above do not work well here; this essentially boils down to the multivariate versions of the results they use (i.e. Padé approximants) not being as efficient as in the one-dimensional case.
Any references to literature about this kind of problem would be much appreciated!
Filaseta, Michael; Trifonov, Ognian, On gaps between squarefree numbers. II, J. Lond. Math. Soc., II. Ser. 45, No. 2, 215-221 (1992). ZBL0799.11032.

I just wanted to point out that an Indian mathematician recently gave an improvement to $x^{1/5}$. See here. Hopefully he can provide a helpful comment.
